# NodeJS/MongoDB: How can I access a field in my model from my controller?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I would like to directly access the `character` enum array that exists in my model, from my controller, so that I don't have to hard code the array in my controller. Is there an easy way to do this, or should I just store the array as a variable in my model and then export it along with the model?

**testModel.js:**

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      character: {
        type: String,
        enum: [
          "mario",
          "luigi",
          "link",
          "samus"
        ],
        required: [true, "Please provide a character"],
      },
    });

const Savestate = mongoose.model("Test", testSchema);
module.exports = Test;
```

**controller.js**

```
exports.getCharacterSavestates = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {

// Instead of this array I want to do something like: const characters = model.character.enum
  const characters = [
    "mario",
    "luigi",
    "link",
    "samus",
  ]; 

  if (!characters.includes(req.params.character)) {
    return next(new AppError("Character name invalid"), 400);
  }

  const documents = await Model.find({ character: req.params.character });
  res.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
    results: .length,
    data: { data: documents },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **schema.path** to retrive enum values

```
const Model = require('./testmodel');

exports.getCharacterSavestates = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
const characterEnum = Model.schema.path('character').enumValues; // us

if (!characterEnum.includes(req.params.character)) {
return next(new AppError("Character name invalid"), 400);
}

const documents = await Model.find({ character: req.params.character });
res.status(200).json({
status: "success",
results: documents.length,
data: { data: documents },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **testSchema.paths.character.options.enum** to retrieve that enum.

Example:
[image]

Or you can have defined that enum array separated and use it on multiple places..